# Quicksave Inline Editing on a PageBlock table

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, inlineeditsupport

I have a pageblock table and I enabled InlineEditingSupport. However, everytime I edit it and click quick save, the last row is the only record that is being updated. I tried making my own method but I don't think I am getting it right.
[image]

VF PAGE

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Tiers">
        <p style="font-size: 150%;"><b>Quote Number:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Name}</p><br/><br/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!existingTiers}" var="tiers">
            <apex:column headerValue="Tier Start" value="{!tiers.Tier_Start__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Tier End" value="{!tiers.Tier_End__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="PMPM" value="{!tiers.Price__c}"/>
            <apex:inlineEditSupport/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
             <apex:commandButton value="Quick Save" Action="{!Quicksave}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>




    <apex:pageBlock title="Add Tiers">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Tier Start</th>
                <th>Tier End</th>
                <th>PMPM</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!listTier}" var="Addtier">
                <tr>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 15%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Tier_Start__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 15%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Tier_End__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 30%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Price__c}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Add" Action="{!add}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" Action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" Action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class Quote_AdditionalTiersController {
ApexPages.StandardController sController;
public SBQQ__Quote__c getQuote{get; set;}
public Additional_Tier__c setAT{get; set;}
public List<Additional_Tier__c> listTier{get; set;}
public List<Additional_Tier__c> existingTiers{get; set;}


public Quote_AdditionalTiersController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    sController = sc;
    this.getQuote = (SBQQ__Quote__c)sc.getRecord();
    setAT = new Additional_Tier__c();

    listTier = new List<Additional_Tier__c>{
        new Additional_Tier__c(Quote__c = getQuote.Id)
            };

                existingTiers = [SELECT Id, Quote__c, Tier_Start__c, Tier_End__c, Price__c FROM Additional_Tier__c WHERE Quote__c =: getQuote.Id];

}

public void add(){
    listTier.add(new Additional_Tier__c(Quote__c = getQuote.Id));
}

public PageReference save() {
    // setAT.Quote__c= getQuote.Id;
    List<Additional_Tier__c> newTier = new List<Additional_Tier__c>();
    for(Additional_Tier__c tier: listTier){
        if(tier.Tier_Start__c != null && tier.Tier_End__c != null && tier.Price__c != null ){
            newTier.add(tier);
        }
    }
    insert newTier;
    return new PageReference ('/'+getQuote.Id);
}

public PageReference Quicksave(){
    sController.save();
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/Quote_AdditionalTiers?id='+sController.getId());
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

}

Comment: could you highlight exactly what part of your code does not seem to work as you expect?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my Quicksave constructor

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve this by modifying my vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="SBQQ__Quote__c" extensions="Quote_AdditionalTiersController" >
<apex:form >        
    <apex:pageBlock title="Tiers">
        <p style="font-size: 150%;"><b>Quote Number:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Name}</p><br/><br/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!existingTiers}" var="tiers" >              
            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputField value="{!tiers.Tier_Start__c}" id="TierStart" /> 
                <apex:facet name="header">Tier Start</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputField value="{!tiers.Tier_End__c}" id="TierEnd" /> 
                <apex:facet name="header">Tier End</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputField value="{!tiers.Price__c}" id="Price" /> 
                <apex:facet name="header">PMPM</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>   
            <apex:inlineEditSupport />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Quick Save" Action="{!Quicksave}" id="saveBtn"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>                 
    </apex:pageBlock>        
    <apex:pageBlock title="Add Tiers">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Tier Start</th>
                <th>Tier End</th>
                <th>PMPM</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!listTier}" var="Addtier">
                <tr>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 15%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Tier_Start__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 15%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Tier_End__c}" /></td>
                    <td class="withborder" style="width: 30%;"><apex:inputField value="{!Addtier.Price__c}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="Add" Action="{!add}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" Action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" Action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

I had to separate each  by using opening and closing indent and use  to display the fields.